# What math field can deduce equations for a hand-drawn shape?

Tags: math, graph, autocad, adobe-illustrator

Suppose I have an Arabic character hand-drawn in Thuluth font, as in: 
http://arabicletters.info/wp-content/uploads/1.jpg

I was thinking of a way I can recreate the same shape but at a much greater height, whilst leaving the other characteristics intact (stroke width, thickness, the relation of where the curving starts to happen to the height) which then got me curious about a way of finding its mathematical representation and play with it until I can get what I want or any other shape for that matter. Is there a math sub-specialty that can help with this? and for this particular problem, can it be solved using programs like Adobe Illustrator or AutoCAD?

Forgive the noobness.

Comment: I may want to look for "raster vectorization". There is an open source vector editor http://inkscape.org/ which allows to vectorize raster image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think deduce is the right word.

You can get what you want if you add sufficient points and do Bezier spline fits to match the letters.

There might be a way to automate the process of adding points, but the "sufficient" criterion is tricky.  And then you'd have to tell how to connect points with splines.

Sounds like you're trying to reproduce optical character recognition in Arabic.